# How to combine multiple objectives for optimization?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I don't know why this is so hard for me to figure out.

For example, I have two functions, *f(x, y)* and *g(x, y)*.  I want to find the values of *x* and *y* such that:

- *f(x, y)* is at a target value (minimize the difference from the target)
- *g(x, y)* is minimized (can be negative, doesn't stop at 0)
- *x* and *y* are bounded (so *g*'s minimum doesn't necessarily have a gradient of 0)

So if I were just finding a solution for *f*, I could minimize `abs(f(x, y) - target)`, for instance, and it will hit zero when it's found a solution.  But there are multiple such solutions and I also want to find the one that minimizes *g*.

So how do I combine these two functions into a single expression that I can then minimize (using a Newton-like method)?

My first attempt was `100*abs(f(x, y) - target) + g(x, y)` to strongly emphasize hitting the target first, and it worked for some cases of the target value, but failed for others, since `g(x, y)` could go so negative that it dominated the combination and the optimizer stopped caring about *f*.  How do I guarantee that *f* hitting the target is always dominant?

Are there general rules for how to combine multiple objectives into a single objective?

Comment: Also, I wish MathJax were enabled here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function#Motivation

Comment: http://www.alglib.net/optimization/nonlinearlyconstrained.php

Answer (score 4):

There is a rich literature about multi-objective optimization. Two popular methods are weighted objective and a lexicographic approach.

A weighted objective could be designed as:

`min w1 * [f-target]^2 + w2 * g`

for some weights `w1, w2 >= 0`. Often we have `w1+w2=1` so we can also write:

`min w1 * [f-target]^2 + (1-w1) * g`

Set w1 to a larger value than w2 to put emphasis on the f objective.

The lexicographic method assumes an ordering of objectives. It can look like:

1. Solve with first objective `z = min [f-target]^2`. Let z* be the optimal objective.
2. Solve with the second objective while staying close to z*:
     `min g subject to [f-target]^2-z* <= tolerance`

To measure the deviation between the target and f I used a quadratic function here. You can also use an absolute value.

Comment: Oh, squared error!  That's smoother than `abs()`; I like that. "Ordering of objectives" sounds exactly like what I want, but is there a way to create a single objective expression that expresses this ordering?  I feel like it would use something like `min(f, g)` (choose the smaller of the two, not your usage of `min`) but I can't think of what it would actually be.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want to get rid the constraint in the second solve of the lexicographic search. My preferred way is to use a solver that can handle constraints (the problems I deal with typically have a lot of constraints). Otherwise there are penalty methods that move the constraints into the objective.Any good book on nonlinear programming will detail such methods.

Comment: "Any good book will detail"  Can you give a specific example to get me started, since I don't know what I'm looking for?

Comment: E.g Nocedal and Wright, Numerical Optimization. However, in almost all cases it is a bad idea to write your own solver (just like writing your own word processor).

Comment: Oh, I don't want to write my own solver. I thought you meant it had examples of how to write objective functions with constraints.  I see now that `scipy.optimize.minimize` does support constraints, but when I try to use them, it gives me incorrect results that don't meet the constraints.  I guess that's a separate question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot exactly get f(x,y)-target to be zero, you have to accept some amount of error. I will use the relative error r = abs((f(x, y) - target)/target).

A function which grows extremely rapidly with r should do the trick.

exp(r/epsilon) + g(x, y)

If I choose epsilon = 1e-10, then I know r has to be less than 1e-7, because exp(1000) is an enormous number, but when r is small, like r = 1e-12, then the exponential changes very slowly, and g(x,y) will be the dominant term. You can even take it a step further and calculate how close x and y are to their true value, but its usually just easier to adjust the parameter until you get what you need.

Comment: Oh I guess I forgot to mention that x and y are bounded, so the derivative of g isn't necessarily 0, if it hits one of the bounds.